# Dynamically resize fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I have a fragment which fill all of the screen. Now, If i add a new fragment i would like that each fragment fill half of the screen. How can I do this?[image]

I tried this layout and programmatically added fragments. But it doesn't work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="tech.test.org.game.Game$PlaceholderFragment">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="50">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        >
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given by Kat-hat is also correct but it takes to much load, to load the UI which may hamper the performance.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
   >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**when you are adding second fragment do programatically set layout2 visibility to visible.**

```
findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: but if you do this then the half of the fragment A is hidden and not resized, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Linear layout instead of Relative layout and set layout as

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="100" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And when you are adding second fragment do programatically set layout2 visibility to visible and layout1 weight to 50

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = layout1.getLayoutParam();
par.weight =50;
```